# warning execution completed with warning stored procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, plsql, oracle11g

i wrote a stored procedure in oracle sql developer to be used later in .netframework app
compiling the stored procedure gave me this message
Warning: execution completed with warning
procedure selection Compiled.

how can i view the warning when googled. results where all advising using command                        "show errors procedure procedure_name"
but it didn't work

the procedure

```
create or replace procedure selection 
(p_id in NUMBER(10),p_name out varchar2(40),p_cat out varchar2(40),stock out number(10),price out 
number(9.2),sup out number(10))
as
begin
select p.prod_name into p_name,p.prod_category into p_cat,p.stock into stock,p.price into 
price,p.sup_id into sup
from product p
where p.prod_id = p_id;
end;
```

Comment: If you're using SQL Developer, there should be a compiler log in the messages window and the errors will be printed to the Script Output window.  You can also query `user_errors` but that shouldn't be necessary.  Are you using an ancient version of SQL Developer (in which case the names of windows may have changed)?

Comment: You do not declare size on parameters.  So try: create or replace procedure selection 
*(p_id in NUMBER,p_name out varchar2,p_cat out varchar2,stock out number,price out 
number,sup out number)*. That might not be all but is obvious at a glance.

Comment: justin cave thank you i found it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this bro

```
create or replace procedure selection 
(p_id in NUMBER,
 p_name out varchar2, 
 p_cat out varchar2, 
 stock out number, 
 price out number ,
 sup out number)
as
begin
select p.prod_name, p.prod_category ,p.stock ,p.price ,p.sup_id 
into p_name, p_cat, stock, price, sup
from product p
where p.prod_id = p_id;
end;
```